# RxJava: add items from different Observables to Subject

Tags: rx-java

I am trying to add items to a Subject,

but I cannot call `Subject.onNext()` because I get the other items from other `Observables`

```
   // My observer subscribes to a ReplaySubject
   subject.subscribe(observer)

   // The first item is emitted (and regularly received by my observer)
   // by the first observable, that after that terminates 
   firstObservable.subscribeWith(subject)

   // Now I have other observables emitting other things, 
   // and I would like to send them to the subject so that the observer receives them,
   // possibly without manually calling subject.onNext()
```

Comment: Are these other `Observable`s known upfront? Why do you create an `Observable` with `just` while you could call `subject.onNext(getOneThing())`?

Comment: Hi, thanks, because I don't have control about what I get, I get all the data I want in the form of observables

Answer (score 2):

Subscribing a `Subject` to multiple `Observable`s are not recommended, but you can merge those `Observable`s and subscribe to that:

```
ReplaySubject<Integer> subject = ReplaySubject.create();

Observable.merge(first, second, third).subscribe(subject);
```

However, you can achieve a similar caching effect via `replay()` and `autoConnect()`:

```
Observable<Integer> cached = 
    Observable.merge(first, second, third).replay().autoConnect();
```

If the sources are dynamically created as well, use a `PublishSubject` and `merge` it:

```
Subject<Observable<Integer>> sources = PublishSubject.<Observable<Integer>>.create()
   .toSerialized();

Observable<Integer> output = Observable.merge(sources).replay().autoConnect();

sources.onNext(Observable.fromCallable(() -> getOneThing()));
sources.onNext(Observable.range(1, 10).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()));
```

Answer (score 1):

By contract, if  a `Subject` `subscribe()` to an `Observable` which terminate, the `Subject` will terminate too.

Instead of using a `Subject` you could use a [`Relay`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay). Basically a `Subject` that doesn't propagate termination from its sources. It implements [`Consumer`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/Consumer.html) instead of [`Observer`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observer.html), but since `subscribe()` accept either of those interface as type parameter `RxRelay` is a drop-in replacement.